# jhipster updating .jhipster/entities.json from java entities

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

When I need to update an entity in jhipster just run jhipster entity MyEntity and apply new changes as desired to both: the entity and the associated changelog. So far so good. But what if I want the inverse result: defining the new fields/relations in the entity class and propagate those changes through the changelog and the frontend entity?
In this case, for instance:

```
@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]")
private String name;
```

According to what I have read, If I already have the name field but I want to add the above validations I have to add them into the proper liquibase changelog first and then in my java entity? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to use this workflow, however, by my understanding it is not possible.

A possible solution would be to first regenerate the entity using jhipster cli or any other jhipster method. Once this step is completed, you could edit the entity in Java, adding complex validations or even refining the entity's relationship.

After any entity modification you must update Liquibase's changelog. You could do it manually or you could run `./gradlew liquibaseDiffChangeLog` to generate a changelog containing all changes applied over the database. Don't forget to apply the generated changelog to the main changelog (`src/main/resources/liquibase/master.xml`).

Cheers!